# iOS - Secure Text Entry Causes Font Size And Style Of Last Character To Be Different

Tags: ios, uitextfield

By default, `secureTextEntry` is set to YES. When the text is entered in the text field, ••••••• will be displayed. But this time. when `secureTextEntry` is set to NO, the font size and style of the last character of the string will always be different. Plus, there will be a big spacing between the cursor and the whole string. See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from this site. http://www.jianshu.com/p/72271c023d6d

After changing the secureTextEntry property of UITextField. Just replace the string with and empty string @" ", then copy the original string back again.

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)secureSwitchAction:(id)sender 
{
    self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = !self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry;

    NSString* text = self.passwordTextField.text;
    self.passwordTextField.text = @" ";
    self.passwordTextField.text = text;
}
```